# NuGet Pack, GitVersionTask, and targeting multiple framework versions

Tags: .net, nuget, gitversion

Normally, when using [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) and GitVersionTask (which generates .NET assembly versions like AssemblyInformationalVersion automatically), I will generate NuGet packages by running the `nuget pack` command against the `.csproj` file, with a `.nuspec` file sitting alongside it. This allows me to use the full set of nuspec [replacement tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens), like $version$, which then takes its value from the AssemblyInformationalVersion that GitVersion generated, removing the need to hard-code these anywhere.

However, in certain circumstances I want to produce NuGet packages that target multiple framework versions (which then go into subfolders under /lib, such as net40, net45, etc.). I would normally do this with separate projects (each targeting a single framework version), with source files added as links into each project. But this then means that `nuget pack` would have multiple .csproj files to deal with, and to my knowledge, NuGet doesn't have any sort of "append" mode that would add to an existing nupkg archive. So that then means suggests that I would need to do `nuget pack` against the [.nuspec directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks), which takes away my ability to use replacement tokens.

So, if I want to be able to use GitVersion to generate the assembly versions automatically, *and* target multiple framework versions, *and* take advantage of the replacement tokens like $version$ to avoid hard-coding them, how can I do it?